# Highcharts with zooming only available for desktop

Tags: highcharts, touch, zooming

I have a Highcharts line chart with the following options (among others).

```js
            var chartOptions = {
              chart: {
                zoomType: 'x',
                pinchType: 'none'
              }
            }
```

Still zooming is available on iPhone. I have tried to set pinchType to null but with no result. The chart has potentially thousands of data points so I want to disable zooming for mobile (=touch) devices and see if that will keep the page and chart more responsive (responsive as in faster).

Comment: How about add add condition which checks resolution and then enable/disable zoom. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3hshaL7u/1/

Comment: @SebastianBochan That seems to work pretty ok. The problem was earlier that if the chart would fill up the whole phone screen (e.g. in landscape mode) it was hard to move the page without zooming the chart because it felt like it was zooming on touch and not only on pinch. Now I can move over the chart but if the chart fills the whole screen it seems to hang up for a short while but eventually get's over it.